# JS Object.assign without adding additional key/value

Tags: javascript

I am interested in to assign values to only those keys that are available in destination object from source object.

```
const destination= {
    name: "John Doe", 
    age: 24,
}
const source= {
    name: "Usman Khan", 
    age: 36,
    title: "Full stack developer",
    location: "Remote"
}
```

if I use Object.assign it merges both object same with the spread operator.

I am only interested to assign values to keys available in destination object i.e. Only Name and age, not to merge the two objects without loops and if conditions or any other efficient method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) and a `forEach` loop along with the [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator.

`Object.entries()` gives you an array of entries `[key,value]` in the object.

```js
const destination= {
    name: "John Doe", 
    age: 24,
};
const source= {
    name: "Usman Khan", 
    age: 36,
    title: "Full stack developer",
    location: "Remote"
};

Object.entries(source).forEach( ([key,value]) => {
      if(key in destination) destination[key] = value;
});
console.log(destination);
console.log(source);
```

Answer (score 3):

You still need some iterations.

```js
const
    getProperty = object => key => ({ [key]: object[key] }),
    destination= { name: "John Doe", age: 24 },
    source= { name: "Usman Khan", age: 36, title: "Full stack developer", location: "Remote" };

Object.assign(
    destination, 
    ...Object
        .keys(destination)
        .map(getProperty(source))
);

console.log(destination);
```

Comment: @ikhvjs, yes, this would work as assignment, but not with `const` declaration.

Comment: Your solution is correct. The `destination` object may contain properties that `source` doesn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over `destination` using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), while checking if every property is in `source` using [`Object#hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) to update its value.

```js
const 
  destination = { name: "John Doe", age: 24 },
  source = { name: "Usman Khan", age: 36, title: "Full stack developer", location: "Remote" };
  
for(const prop in destination) {
  if(source.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    destination[prop] = source[prop];
  }
}

console.log(destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be reduced to:

1. Find properties that exist on both `destination` *and* `source`.
2. Assign these properties from `source` to `destination`.

Here is an example implementation:

```js
const destination = { name: "John Doe", age: 24 };
const source = {
  name: "Usman Khan",
  age: 36,
  title: "Full stack developer",
  location: "Remote"
};

console.log(assignExisting(destination, source));

function assignExisting(destination, source) {
  const sourceKeys = allKeys(source);
  for (const key in destination) {
    if (sourceKeys.includes(key)) { // If in both destination and source
      destination[key] = source[key]; // then assign property
    }
  }
  
  return destination;
}
function allKeys(o) { // See excursus for why I use this
  const keys = [];
  for (const p in o) keys.push(p);
  return keys;
}
```

## Excursus: Prototypes, properties and `delete`

[JavaScript is prototype-based](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain), which means that objects are or may have prototypes. Since prototypes are objects themselves, they naturally can have properties as well.

When an object and a prototype of it have a property of similar name, the object's property shadows the prototype's property. This does not override the prototype's property.

This means an object can have *own* properties and *inherited* properties. To find whether a property is an object's own, you can use [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Simply assigning `undefined` to an object's property will however not delete it: It will *still* shadow the prototype's properties. To actually *delete* a property, use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

```js
function ExampleObject() {}
ExampleObject.prototype.value = "inherited";

const object = new ExampleObject();

console.log("object.value");
console.log("-Before shadowing: " + object.value);

object.value = "own";
console.log("-After shadowing: " + object.value);

object.value = undefined;
console.log("-After assigning undefined: " + object.value);

delete object.value;
console.log("-After deleting own property: " + object.value);
```

[`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) returns an array of own properties; [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loops over all (own and inherited) properties.

Returning to the original question: Since we want to assign all properties that both `destination` and `source` have, we need to consider the inherited properties as well. `Object.keys()` won't allow us to do so, which is why I use my `allKeys()` function and a `for...in` loop.